# Linear Algebra Book

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

What  are  useful  books  on  Linear  ALgebra?  I  need  theoretical , abstract  approach  but  most  of  the  proofs  are  explained  with  detail. 
In  general  how  can  we  improve  our  linear  algebra  knowledge  to  solve problems in  Putnam  Competition  or  similar  Competition  programs ?

Comment: Most  of  people  say  that  Gilbert  Strange  but  it  is  not  useful  for  training  Putnam  Competition

Answer (score 1):

I use Elementary Linear Algebra, $11^{th}$ Edition by Howard Anton (Professor Emeritus, Drexel University) and Chris Rorres (University of Pennsylvania).

This, to me, is a very nice book when starting with Linear Algebra.